# Subtracting and adding strings in python 3.0

Tags: python-3.x

```
I want to subtract two strings like so:
health = "100"
nuke = "50"
health = health - nuke
print(health)
```

It is meant to assign the new value '50' as the health but when i do this i get: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python is not js, you cannot subtract string from string. Convert them to number:

```
print(int(health) - int(nuke))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
health = 100
nuke = 50
health = health - nuke
print(health)
```

This keeps the code nice and tidy instead of having to change things into intergers